# CMake: Executable Not Recompiling on Library Change

Tags: c++, cmake

Ultimately, I would like some executable to generate a header file filled with static data. Then use that static data throughout the code, using compile time optimization. So, unlike some other solutions I've seen, a longer compile time is intended. I don't think using a configure_file will be easy, because this may be a complex ordering of data retrieved from various sources - such as a database.

The following is what I have so far. Which this works, but only on the first build of the executable. The issue I'm running into to is the executable does not recompile if the generated header does. Although, the binaries of the static library does differ.

Example below:

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(ExampleGenerator test/ExampleGenerator.cpp)

set(GENERATED_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${GENERATED_DIR}/ExampleData.h
    COMMAND ExampleGenerator > ${GENERATED_DIR}/ExampleData.h
    DEPENDS ExampleGenerator 
    COMMENT "Generating ExampleData.h"
)
add_custom_target(ExampleData ALL DEPENDS ${GENERATED_DIR}/ExampleData.h)
add_library(ExampleLib STATIC gen/ExampleData.cc ${GENERATED_DIR}/ExampleData.h)
include_directories(${GENERATED_DIR})
add_dependencies(ExampleLib ExampleData)

add_executable(ExampleExecutable test/ExampleExecutable.cc)
target_link_libraries(ExampleExecutable ExampleLib)
```

where the "ExampleData.cc" is just a file with the following.

```
#include "ExampleData.h"
```

And the ExampleExecutable may print something like:
Version = 1

Even though the ExampleData.h correctly generated with
Version = 2

CMake version is 3.17.5

Comment: Just add `${GENERATED_DIR}/ExampleData.h` into the `add_executable` call, like you added it into `add_library` call.

Comment: Do you have some git repo with that example? It looks like it should just work.

Comment: Try moving `${GENERATED_DIR}/ExampleData.h` to `target_sources` this way: `target_sources(ExampleLib PUBLIC ${GENERATED_DIR}/ExampleData.h)`. Note that `PUBLIC` keyword is important!

Comment: Also do not use `include_directories` - this is old deprecated functionality. Use modern cmake API: `target_include_directories(ExampleLib PUBLIC ${GENERATED_DIR})`

Comment: @MarekR, it looks like it should work because I think it does work... 
I was working on moving the example code into it's own repo. However, it was working in it's own environment. So, after clearing all files in the original project's CMake "build" folder, it began to work as expected. My best guess is this was something cached by CMake from my previous attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue seems to be that previous attempts dirtied the CMake cache. Clearing the CMake cache (rm -rf the build folder) solved my issue without changing the example code.

Comment: You don't have to wipe the whole build folder. Generally `rm -rf CMakeCache CMakeFiles/` is enough.